# STRIPE API Payment Intent incomplete payment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, stripe-payments

I've been using Stripe. When checkout X will create a Payment Intent every time a customer arrives on the checkout. This will result into an "Incomplete" payment.

[image]

I integrete STRIPE in my .Net Core application. Here the code below :

```
 public void Pay(CardInfo cardInfo, double amount)
        {
            StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = _paramList["secretKey"];
            State = PaymentState.Pending;
            try
            {
                var options = new SessionCreateOptions
                {
                    Mode = "payment",
                    SuccessUrl = "https://example.com/success",
                    CancelUrl = "https://example.com/cancel",
                    Customer = cardInfo.Owner,
                    CustomerEmail = cardInfo.ParamList["email"],                                    
                    PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>
                    {
                        "card",
                    },
                    LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
                {
                  new SessionLineItemOptions
                  {
                    Amount = Convert.ToInt64(amount.ToString().Replace(",","")),
                    Currency = "eur",
                    Quantity = 1,
                    Name = _paramList["account"]                  
                  },
                },
                    
                };

                var service = new SessionService();
                service.Create(options);
                State = PaymentState.Accepted;
            }
            catch (StripeException error)
            {        
                State = PaymentState.Error;
                PaymentReturn = error.Message;
                Logger.Write(string.Format("Error STRIPE payment status {0} : ",PaymentReturn));
            }
      }
```

In my form payment, I'm not using stripe form but I've created one and I retrieve all information that I need (Card Number, CVV, Expiration, Email and Amount)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Stripe Checkout, a PaymentIntent is created under the hood to support the SCA compliant payment. If the session is not completed, the PaymentIntent will remain in state `incomplete`. This. part is entirely normal.

Integrating with Stripe using a checkout session, but not redirecting to the Stripe hosted Checkout is not a supported integration. If you would like to support handling the card fields yourself, then an integration using Stripe.js and Elements is the best way forward [1]. If you would like to continue using Stripe Checkout as it offers so much functionality out of the box, then once the session is created, you should use redirectToCheckout() from Stripe.js [2] to send the user to Stripe Checkout.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=elements

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#redirect-customers